# Dataimport fails for large data in SOLR

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have setup SOLR. I used to import data (1 lakh) into solr index which works properly.

Now i am trying to import large data (10+ lakhs records) into solr index. i have setup data-config.xml then i start full-import but it fails and give error mentioned below

**Indexing failed. Rolled back all changes.**

I store solr start log in solr.err file which gives error:

```
Jul 31, 2012 10:19:33 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
SEVERE: Ignoring Error when closing connection
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:637)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4749)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2627)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:841)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:681)
    ... 6 more
Jul 31, 2012 10:19:44 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
SEVERE: Ignoring Error when closing connection
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:637)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2709)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2709)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2627)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:841)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:681)
    ... 6 more
Jul 31, 2012 10:19:44 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
```

`SEVERE: Ignoring Error when closing connection
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:637)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)`

```
Jul 31, 2012 10:19:44 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: end_rollback
Jul 31, 2012 10:19:44 AM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource closeConnection
SEVERE: Ignoring Error when closing connection

com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (7959657 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:637)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:420)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3118)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2288)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2709)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollbackNoChecks(ConnectionImpl.java:4863)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4749)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4358)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:1607)
```

@                                                                                ataConfig.java:342)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:383)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:445)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:426)

I use 4 core processor with 4GB RAM.

**What mysql/java configuration changes required to resolve this issue?**

Comment: Didn't you see that MySQL reported "You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable"? That's all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this has more to do with Mysql than with Solr, as mysql jdbc driver is having the issue. Try [this workaround here](http://help.hannonhill.com/kb/common-error-messages/mysql-packet-for-query-is-too-large), that just uppers the limit of data mysql can handle.

Comment: Even after setting max_allowed_packet it was giving java heap space issue which is resolved by increasing heap size while starting solr with java -Xmx1582m -jar start.jar